# Does HelpNDoc Pascal Script support structures?

Tags: pascalscript, helpndoc

I am trying to create a structure:

```
MyTopic
    TopicID : String;
    HelpID : Integer;
```

I wanted to create an array of these structures so I could sort them.

I have tried using this `type` / `record` syntax but it is failing.

## Update

I defined this `type` and `procedure`:

```pascal
type
    TMyTopicRecord = record
        idTopic : String;
        idContextHelp : integer;
    End;

procedure GetSortedTopicIDs(aTopics : array of String; size : Integer);
var
    aMyTopicRecords : array of TMyTopicRecord;
    temp : TMyTopicRecord;
    iTopic, i, j : Integer;
begin
    // Init the array
    SetLength(aMyTopicRecords, size); 

    // Fill the array with the existing topid ids.
    // Get the context ids at the same time.
    for iTopic := 0 to size - 1 do
        aMyTopicRecords[iTopic].idTopic := aTopics[iTopic];
        aMyTopicRecords[iTopic].idContextHelp := HndTopics.GetTopicHelpContext(aTopics[iTopic]);

    // Sort the array on context id
    for i := size-1 DownTo 1 do
    for j := 2 to i do
        if (aMyTopicRecords[j-1].idContextHelp > aMyTopicRecords[j].idContextHelp) Then
        begin
            temp := aMyTopicRecords[j-1];
            aMyTopicRecords[j-1] := aMyTopicRecords[j];
            aMyTopicRecords[j] := temp;
        end;

    // Rebuild the original array of topic ids
    for iTopic := 0 to size - 1 do
        aTopics[iTopic] := aMyTopicRecords[iTopic].idTopic;
end;
```

The procedure gets called in a loop of the **parent** function (code snipped):

```pascal
function GetKeywordsAsHtml(): string;
var
    aKeywordList: THndKeywordsInfoArray;
    aAssociatedTopics: array of string;
    nBlocLevel, nDif, nClose, nCurKeywordLevel, nCurKeywordChildrenCnt: Integer;
    nCurKeyword, nCurKeywordTopic: Integer;
    nCountAssociatedTopics: Integer;
    sCurrentKeyword, sKeywordLink, sKeywordRelated: string;
    sKeywordJsCaption: string;
begin
    Result := '<ul>';
    nBlocLevel := 0;
    try
        aKeywordList := HndKeywords.GetKeywordList(False);
        for nCurKeyword := 0 to length(aKeywordList) - 1 do
        begin
            sCurrentKeyword := aKeywordList[nCurKeyword].id;
            nCurKeywordLevel := HndKeywords.GetKeywordLevel(sCurrentKeyword);
            nCurKeywordChildrenCnt := HndKeywords.GetKeywordDirectChildrenCount(sCurrentKeyword);

            sKeywordLink := '#';
            sKeywordRelated := '[]';

            aAssociatedTopics := HndTopicsKeywords.GetTopicsAssociatedWithKeyword(sCurrentKeyword);
            nCountAssociatedTopics := Length(aAssociatedTopics);
            if nCountAssociatedTopics > 0 then
            begin
                GetSortedTopicIDs(aAssociatedTopics, nCountAssociatedTopics);
                // Code snipped
            end;
        end;
    finally
        Result := Result + '</ul>';
    end;
end;
```

The script **compiled** in the HelpNDoc **internal editor** with no issues. But when I go to actually build my HTML documentation I encounter a problem:

[image: HelpNDoc Error]

The HelpNDoc API is explained [here](https://www.helpndoc.com/documentation/html/HelpNDocAPImethods.html).

Is there something wrong with my code?

Comment: @MartinPrikryl Please see my updated question.

Comment: @MartinPrikryl As far as I am aware HelpNDoc does not offer any debug features. In short, I do not know how to debug this script and they don't offer support for "scripts" authoring.

Comment: So just try removing the lines until you get the minimal (even if useless) code that does not cause the exception.

Comment: @MartinPrikryl If the line 449 actually represents that in my script it would be: `aMyTopicRecords[iTopic].idTopic := aTopics[iTopic];`.

Comment: Should the `aMyTopicRecords` parameter be declared as `var`? -- `var aTopics : array of String`

Comment: @MartinPrikryl Sadly, using `var` did not stop the error.

Comment: Did you try to inline the function to the `GetKeywordsAsHtml`?

Comment: @MartinPrikryl Don't know how to do that.

Comment: @MartinPrikryl I cab fill in the `temp` variable with the values of the first item in `aTopics`. So it is my own array objects that is not good.

Comment: [Mcve], please :)

Comment: @MartinPrikryl I found a workaround. Please see my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I decided to go about it a different way and used a simpler technique:

```pascal
procedure GetSortedTopicIDs(var aTopics : array of String; iNumTopics : Integer);
var
    iTopic : Integer;
    // List of output
    aList: TStringList;
begin
    // Init list
    aList := TStringList.Create;

    // Build a new array of "nnn x"
    //  - nnn is the help context id
    //  - x is the topid id

    // Note: I know that the context ID values are within the range 0 - 200
    for iTopic := 0 to iNumTopics - 1 do
        // We pad the context id with 0. We could increase the padding width to
        // make the script mre useful
        aList.Add(Format('%0.3d %s', [
            HndTopics.GetTopicHelpContext(aTopics[iTopic]),
            aTopics[iTopic]
        ]));

    // Now we sort the new array (which basically sorts it by context id)
    aList.Sort; 

    // Update original array
    for iTopic := 0 to iNumTopics - 1 do
        // We ignore the "nnn " part of the string to get just the topic id
        aTopics[iTopic] := copy(aList[iTopic],5, length(aList[iTopic])-4);

    // Tidy up      
    aList.Free;
end;
```

This compiles and I get the sorted array of topic IDs at the end of it. So the pop-up help is now listed as I want.

Comment: Just to say that the software authors confirmed that records are supported.